# Is it possible for an absolutely positioned div to break out of it's container

Tags: html, css

I have seen the similar questions to this but the difference is I can provide a test case and I have not found a solution.

I am using a ccs only implementation of parallax. The problem is that I need a form in the footer that can be fixed to the bottom of the window when the screen is 768px or bigger. I cannot find a way to break it out of its parent box though (using positioned fixed or absolute).

Any suggestions? Javascript last resort only please. Any more info required let me know.

live example http://www.perthminiexcavatorhire.com.au/

HTML

```
<!--MAIN -->
<!--===============================================================-->
 <main class="main">

   <section class="slides row"><!-- absolute-->    
     <div class="slide" id="slide-1"><!-- relative-->    
      <div class="slide__bg"></div><!-- absolute--> 

         <div class="slide__text row">

             <div class="well panel_well one_edge_shadow row" >
                <?php include 'includes/content/panel1.php'; ?>
             </div>     

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide-2"> <!-- absolute-->   
    <div class="slide__bg one_edge_shadow"></div><!-- relative-->   
    <div class="slide__content row"><!-- absolute-->    

    <div class="slide__testomonial">

        <section class="row">       
                <?php include 'includes/content/embedded-video.php'; ?>    
        </section>

    </div> 
    </div>  
    </div>
<!-- Panel3 ==========================================-->

    <div class="slide" id="slide-3"><!-- absolute-->    
        <div class="slide__bg"></div><!-- relative-->   
        <div class="slide__content row"><!-- absolute-->    

        <div class="slide__text">

            <div class="well panel_well one_edge_shadow row">
                <?php include 'includes/content/panel2.php'; ?>
            </div>  

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>     

<!-- FORM==========================================-->
<div class="slide " id="slide-4"><!-- absolute-->   
    <div class="slide__bg"></div><!-- relative-->   
        <div class="slide__content row"><!-- absolute-->    

        <section class="footer slide__footer"> 
            <?php include 'includes/content/form.php'; ?>    
        </section>

    </div>
</div>
</section>      
</main>
```

CSS

```
/*FORM*/
   form{position: fixed; bottom: 0;left: 0; width: 100%;background-color: black;display: block;}

/* PARALLAX STYLES
--------------------------------------------- */
.slides{overflow: hidden}

.slide {
    position: relative;/*to background*/    
}

/* slide background */
.slide__bg {
  position: absolute;/*in relation to slide container*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;/*bottom layer*/;
}
#slide-1 .slide__bg {
    background-color: darkcyan;
}
/*non critical styling*/
#slide-2 .slide__bg {
    background-color: darkmagenta;
}
/*non critical styling*/
#slide-3 .slide__bg {
  background-color: darkgoldenrod
}
/*non critical styling*/
#slide-4 .slide__bg {
    background-color: darkblue;
}

.slides {
    position: absolute;/*position container in window*/
    width: 100%;/*fill container*/
    height: 100%;/*fill container*/
    perspective: 400px;/*dictates size of slide--bg*/
    overflow-x: hidden;/*hide scroll bar*/
    overflow-y: auto;/*hide scroll bar*/
    }

.slides::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;/*hide scroll bar*/ 
}

/* Only apply to larger screens
--------------------------------------------- */ 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  /* parallax */
  @supports ((perspective: 1px) and (not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch))) {
    body {
      transform: translateZ(0px); /* Fix paint issues in Edge && Safari H/W acceleration */
    }


.slide, .slide__content {
      transform-style: preserve-3d;/* maintain perspective effect*/ 
    }

  .slide__text {
      transform: translateZ(60px) scale(.7);/*set text distance from page and scale*/
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;/*position of text on slide*/
        /*background-color: aqua;   */
      background-color: red;
      height: 800px;
    }


.slide__testomonial {
      transform: translateZ(80px) scale(.7);/*set text distance from page and scale*/
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;/*position of text on slide*/
        background-color: aqua;
    height: 800px;
    }

.slide__footer {
    transform: translateZ(60px) scale(.7);/*set text distance from page and scale*/
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;/*position of text on slide*/
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    }



    .slide:nth-child(2n) {
      z-index: 1; /* ensure EVERY OTHER SLIDE overlays correctly */
    }

    .slide:nth-child(2n+1):not(:first-child) .slide__bg {
      top: -16%;/*SELECTS EVERY ODD SLIDE NOT INCLUDING FIRST - extend slide__bg to meet next bg to fill gap*/
         bottom: -50%;/*SELECTS EVERY ODD SLIDE NOT INCLUDING
    }

    .slide:nth-child(2n) .slide__bg {
      transform: translateZ(59px) scale(.85);/*SELECTS EVERY EVEN SLIDE AFTER THE FIRST - set background distance from page and scale to match window*/
    }

    .slide:nth-child(2n+1):not(:last-child) .slide__bg {
      bottom: -50%;/*SELECTS EVERY ODD SLIDE NOT INCLUDING LAST extend slide__bg to meet next bg to fill gap*/
    }


    }
```

Comment: Summary: How do I position the absolute child of a relative parent of an absolute grandparent at a fixed position at bottom:0, width:100% in relation to the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly your container has

```
position: relative
```

example with JS, add this under you html element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var elem = document.getElementById("yourElement");
document.body.appendChild(elem);
};
</script>
```

Comment: It does but it has to be that way for the parallax effect as its the child of another absolute container. That my problem. How do I position the absolute child of a relative parent of an absolute grandparent in relation to the window?

Comment: only with moving you element dynamically with js outside

Comment: If that's the only way can you help with an example? I'm also having a google now.

Comment: added some solution for you :)

Comment: Thanks but how would I adapt this with media queries so it only happens +768px?

Comment: you can add if clause for window width with this ->window.innerWidth<-